# Evaluate $ \int_{\varepsilon}^1 \sin\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $0 < \varepsilon < 1$, how to solve the integral:
$$
 \int_{\varepsilon}^1 \sin\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) dx
$$

Comment: Have you tried substituting 1/x as y and then evaluating it by parts?

Comment: @stefan I think this question asked before.. did you do enough research ?

Comment: @Airbag: I could not find it...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660425/integration-of-sin-frac1x

Comment: Maple says this here $-\sin \left( {{\it epsilon}}^{-1} \right) {\it epsilon}+{\it Ci}
 \left( {{\it epsilon}}^{-1} \right) +\sin \left( 1 \right) -{\it Ci}
 \left( 1 \right) 
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=x^{-1}$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_{\varepsilon}^1\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx&=\int_{1/\varepsilon}^1(\sin t)(-t^{-2})dt\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_1^{1/\varepsilon}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}t^{2k-1-2}}{(2k-1)!}dt\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\left[\frac{(1/\varepsilon)^{2k-2}}{(2k-1)!(2k-2)}-\frac{1}{(2k-1)!(2k-2)}\right]dt
\end{align*}